# Is the Selenium tutorial on guru99.com still correct?

Tags: selenium-ide

I am going through the Selenium tutorials on www.guru99.com. See: https://www.guru99.com/locators-in-selenium-ide.html

There is one thing which I am not understanding. I am not sure if it is due to me not following the instruction correctly or if something is wrong with the tutorial itself. The instruction in the webpage above, Step 2 says the following: Launch Selenium IDE and enter "id=email" in the Target box. Click the Find button and notice that the "Email or Phone" text box becomes highlighted with yellow and bordered with green, meaning, Selenium IDE was able to locate that element correctly.

When I launched Selenium IDE whilst running this page in Firefox Developer Edition, it asked me to create a new project which I did. Then I started the recording. Whilst in recording mode I then entered "id=email" in the Target box and clicked Find. Nothing happened. The text box is not highlighted whatsoever with yellow and bordered with green.

Is the instruction above outdated or wrong? When I used the Inspector from Firefox Developer Edition to view the text box, it is just fine as I could see the 'id=email' in the Inspector. So I don't understand why I would need to launch IDE and look for "id=email" in the Target box. Just using the Inspector seems sufficient.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Kind regards,
David

Comment: It doesn't highlight for me either - no big deal though, because you know the element exists by using the inspector.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the article doesn't say when it was last updated... so there's a good chance that it's just a little out of date.

You might find that, rather than the field being highlightied yellow, Selenium just 'jumps' to the element if it can be found. If it's not jumping to the element either, then you use `Command Click` and `Target id=email`, which will put a cursor in the field for you.

You're correct in that using the Inspector is sufficient - I think the tutorial is just walking you through some of the Selenium IDE basics.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely the original instructions used the previous version of SeleniumIDE
A new (complete rewrite from scratch) version was recently released.
I just tried it out and was able to figure out your selector as shown below.

To get this correct I had to set the base url as `demo.guru99.com`

and then `open test/facebook.html` and `click id=email`

[image]

[image]

Comment: The base URL is `http://demo.guru99.com/test/facebook.html`, so the target is `name="email"` or `id="email"`

Comment: Thanks @trashpanda yeah I had to set the base url and visit test/facebook.html to get the right page.  Good catch.

Comment: feel free to accept the answer you like best (the "up-arrow/ check") image